# How to check if char array combines to make certain consecutive list of chars?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

For example, my char array may be something like...

```
char array[8] = {0x00,0x07, 0x28, 0xFF, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x71}
```

and I want to check whether char[2] to char[7] is equal to '28 FF AF 00 00 00' hex,
how would I do that in the simplest way? I know I can check each element individually, but I wanted to know if I can somehow specify that I am searching for hex 28FFAF000000 within space char[2] to char[7].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
const bool equal = std::equal(array+2, array+8, "\x28\xff\xaf\x00\x00\x00");
```

`std::equal(start1, end1, start2)` compares element by element the two ranges `[start1, end1)` and `[start2, <end2>)` where `<end2>` is chosen so the two ranges have equal length.

If you're certain to only work with bytes, and if efficiency is important, and you've check that you're compiler doesn't optimize `std::equal` away, you can use the C-ism [`std::memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp):

```
const bool equal = (0 == std::memcmp(array+2, "\x28\xff\xaf\x00\x00\x00", 6));
```

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like:

```
constexpr char expected[] = {0x28, 0xFF, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

return std::equal(std::begin(expected), std::end(expected), array + 2);
```